# EWMA in OpenCPU

Tags: jquery, r, opencpu

I would like to generate control chart (EWMA) in RPlot OpenCPU. I use jQuery.rplot plugin from the opencpu.js library to call the R function called randomplot. included in this R package. But I dont see any function to do so. I checked http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R/. and cant find any function related in that library. Is there anyway to do this?
Thank you

Comment: You're linking to the `stats` package of R. There are others, incl. `graphics`. It would appear OpenCPU does have a `randomplot` function: https://github.com/opencpu/appdemo/blob/master/R/randomplot.R